# TOR Network blocked in Russia

Tags: blocked-services, blocked, tor-network

Are there any plans to circumvent the block of TOR Network in Russia?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Working on it and on step-by-step and automated solution. Most of the locks are implemented on the ISP-provided and managed home routers for end users. Here is the first proven steps that are working in a real field:

- **Use OpenWRT** - you can find a router or you're already *own* one and can re-flash it. Stock firmware uses to succumb to the filtering. You have to have 2+ ARM cores and 512Mb+ on your router with the storage. Just re-flashing *works* in 75%+ of the cases. **You can not re-flash the router provided by your ISP**
- **Rise your very own Tor bridge** and mark it as unpublished. Use Obfs4 - China's censorship seniors are coming here since 2010 even for an official conferences and ZTE and Huawei are promotion is supported by the government, so it's a must to make abridge for yourself and your friends
- **Use diverse Mesh and Darknet nodes** - it will be very hard to block it all *properly* aggregated to help esch other. I'm field testing this link since 2016, now it looks like it's time to make a first public kit. The basic components used are: Yggdrasil, Tor, I2P and ZeroNet

More updates soon(I hope) on my Facebook and direct channels - or drop me a line if you need it here